# is there a clustering algorithm in Spark where the resulting clusters are approximately the same size?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, spark-graphx

i am running a Spark GraphX pregel algorithm where the vertices are intersection coordinates in latitude/longitude, and edges are road segments - a road network. for argument's sake, let's assume uniform message load across the vertices while running the algorithm.

i want to improve performance by providing a better partitioning. my first effort was to create a `PartitionStrategy` which partitioned edges based on clustering their source coordinate. i used the Spark k-means algorithm. then, i realized, while this does a fine job clustering the euclidean points, it tends to do a poor job of load balancing the vertices - cluster sizes vary greatly.

there are agglomerative clustering techniques out there in the wild which will find an approximate solution for this. but, since i'm already in Spark, is there an implementation where it can produce clusters for some *k* that are (approximately) the same size? or, is there a way that i haven't discovered using the built-in mllib tools?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html) you find all the clustering algorithms that Spark currently supports.

Comment: i am familiar with this list; it is how i first selected using the built-in Spark k-means algorithm (as stated above). if any of these algorithms have parameters which can set the target cluster size, then, please elaborate. otherwise, i am looking to know if there are any other implementations that support this objective (built-in, or, found elsewhere but leveraging the Spark framework).